# Troubleshooting foreach/dopar in R with error in larger model function but not in foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, numeric, doparallel

I am working on parallelizing a meta-population (disease) model using *foreach* and *doParallel*. In short, I'm trying to run the same process for each meta-population in parallel (there are ~ 2000 metapopulations). I then run this for 60 days/steps in a larger *for loop*. Here is a simplifed version of the structure (not reproducible unfortunately -- the model is a bit complex to write out here, but I hope this gives the gist of it):

````
loaded.package.names <- c(sessionInfo()$basePkgs, names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs))
loaded.functions <- c("%notin%", "is.blank")
loaded.objects <- c("beta")

model <- function(...){
for(i in 1:timesteps){
y <- foreach(p = 1:nrow(patches_status), 
     .combine = rbind,
     .packages = loaded.package.names, 
     .export = c(loaded.functions, loaded.objects),
     .verbose = TRUE) %dopar% {

exposed.n = data.table(exposed=min(sing_S[p],
        rpois(1, (sing_S[p]*(**beta*sum(sing_I[,p])** + 
              kernels$kernel.tot[p]*sum(sing_I))/(sing_S[p] + 
              sum(sing_E[ ,p]) + sum(sing_I[ ,p]) + sing_R[p]))

return(exposed.n)
} # end foreach loop
} # end timestep loop
                 ```
My issue is that when I run the main function, I get an error in the foreach loop:

**Error in { : task 1 failed - "non-numeric argument to binary operator**

This is related to the multiplication of two values which I believe are both numeric:
 - **beta** : a numeric value of 0.6
 - **sum(sing_I[ ,p])** : a numeric value consisting of the sum of a column extracted from a matrix, determined by the iteration of the loop (i.e., 'p'). This value is frequently zero.

Is one of these values not numeric somehow? Is there another issue?

Strangely, running the foreach loop alone works perfectly.

Thank you for any help!
````

Comment: I would test if the issue also occurs when you run the loop with `%do%`. If it does, great, because without the parallelization debugging is much easier. Even with parallelization, you can always add stuff like `return(beta)` at the beginning of the body of the `foreach` loop, which allows you to inspect these values.

Comment: Thank you for those tips. I couldn't return the error with %do% (worked fine with it) and returning those variables looked good as well. The quest continues,

Comment: Well, strip down your example. If you suspect that `beta*sum(sing_I[,p])` causes the error, do nothing else in the loop.